# Display Template format Start and Due Date MM/DD/YYY

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, display-template

I have a display template that is working awesome but for the formatting of the Managed Property not displaying the date correctly.  I do not want the time included in the display.  I am still learning and really could use some help with this.

The code for the display template is below, in a hope that someone can provide me an answer quickly.

List Table Item-Countermeasures

0</mso:TemplateHidden>
ListID','ListItemID','ContentTypeId','Link URL':'Path','Property 1':'Title','Property 2':'','Property 3':'','Property 4:'','Property 5':'','Property 6':'','Property 7':'','Property 8':'','Property 9':'','Property 10':'','FileExtension','SecondaryFileExtension'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
This is the item row template, use this template in combination with the List Table Control template.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
;#SearchResults;#Content Web Parts;#</mso:TargetControlType>
1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
https://share.philips.com/sites/STS020170908232517/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_List_Item-CM.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
</mso:CrawlerXSLFile>
</mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml>

var encodedId = $htmlEncode(ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId() + "*tableitems*");

var linkURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "Link URL");
linkURL.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);
var iconURL = Srch.ContentBySearch.getIconSourceFromItem(ctx.CurrentItem);

var listID = $getItemValue(ctx, 'ListID');
var listItemID = $getItemValue(ctx, 'ListItemID');
var ContentTypeId = $getItemValue(ctx, 'ContentTypeId');

var startDate = new Date($getItemValue(ctx, "Start Date"));

var rowId = encodedId + "row";
var editCellId = rowId + "_cell";

var currentItemIdx = ctx.CurrentItemIdx + 1;
var alternating = currentItemIdx % 2 === 0 ? "ms-alternating" : "";

if (currentItemIdx === 1) {
_#-->

```
        <!--#_ 

        // Show the properties that aren't empty
        for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { 
            var property = $getItemValue(ctx, String.format("Property {0}", i));
            if(property.managedPropertyName !== String.format("Property {0}", i)) {
                var propertyName = typeof propertyNames[property.propertyLookupName] === "undefined" ? property.managedPropertyName : propertyNames[property.propertyLookupName];
        _#-->
        <th class="ms-vh2">
            _#= propertyName =#_ 

            <span id="_#= property.managedPropertyName.replace(/ /g, '-') =#_">
                <span style="" class="sortarrow ms-sortarrowup-iconouter" ></span>
                <a id="_#= property.managedPropertyName =#_ASC" href="#" title="Ascending" onclick="$getClientControl(this).sortOrRank('_#= property.managedPropertyName =#_ASC');return false;">
                    <img alt="Ascending" src="/_layouts/15/images/sortaz.gif">
                </a>
                <a id="_#= property.managedPropertyName =#_DES" href="#" title="Descending" onclick="$getClientControl(this).sortOrRank('_#= property.managedPropertyName =#_DES');return false;">
                    <img alt="Descending" src="/_layouts/15/images/sortza.gif">
                </a>
            </span>
        </th>
        <!--#_ 
            }
        } 
        _#-->
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

{1}", linkURL, property) : property;
                    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(property.value) === '[object Date]') {value = property.value.format('MM/dd/yyyy');
}

```
        _#-->
                _#= value =#_
        <!--#_
                    if (i === 1 && !listID.isEmpty && !listItemID.isEmpty && !ContentTypeId.isEmpty) {
                        var viewPropUrl = String.format('/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?ListId={0}&ID={1}&ContentTypeID={2}&Source={3}', listID, listItemID, ContentTypeId, window.location.href.split('#')[0]);
        _#-->
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <span title="Open Menu" class="NotificationDiv ms-ellipsis-a" rel="_#= viewPropUrl =#_" ref="_#= property =#_" path="_#= linkURL =#_" style="cursor: pointer; margin-top: 3px; float: right;">
                            <img alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png" class="ms-ellipsis-icon">
                        </span>
        <!--#_
                    }
                }
        _#-->
            </td>
        <!--#_
            }
        } 
        _#-->
    </tr>
```

Thank you in advance.

Dorinda

UPDATE:  the template is now rendering but the format is still not correct. I need help getting this working please

Comment: I have this partially working but really could use some help the formatting is not applying.

Answer (score 0):

After below line:

```
var startDate = new Date($getItemValue(ctx, "Start Date"));
```

Use below code:

```
var startDateFormatted = (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + startDate.getDate() + '/' +  startDate.getFullYear();
```

And use `startDateFormatted` to show on the page instead of `startDate`.

**Update**:

Try replacing `value = property.value.format('MM/dd/yyyy');` with below code:

```
value = (property.value.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + property.value.getDate() + '/' +  property.value.getFullYear();
```

Comment: do i remove the line and replace with the one you provided? I added what you suggested and it now has broken the display template

Comment: No... Don't replace... Just place it after startDate initialization line.... And use code from updated answer... There was missing parenthesis

Comment: I added var startDateFormatted = new Date($getItemValue(ctx, "Start Date"));
var startDateFormatted = (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + startDate.getDate() + '/' +  startDate.getFullYear(); but it is still not working do i need to add anything down in the actual html?

Comment: Yes, in html wherever you have used the startDate reference replace it with startDateFormatted

Comment: the only place i reference a date is here              <!--#_
                    if(!property.isEmpty)
                    {
                        var value = i === 1 ? String.format("<a href='{0}' class='ms-listlink'>{1}</a>", linkURL, property) : property;
     if (Object.prototype.toString.call(property.value) === '[object Date]') {value = property.value.format('MM/dd/yyyy');
}

            _#-->       I dont know what to put?

Comment: Try to debug the code and check what is the value stored in "property.value"... And let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90400/discussion-between-ganesh-sanap-and-dorinda).

Comment: Not sure how to do that?  Like i said I am new to this sorry to be a pain

Comment: I still do not have this working it is giving me an undefined error in the console.  It appears that i am missing something

Comment: I really need help can anyone assist please